# .NET TPL Declaration issues

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.6

I am having a difficult time understanding the TPL and I cannot find many clear articles on it. Most seem to use simplistic examples with lambda expressions.

I have a C# function

```
int[] PlayGames(int[][] boardToSearch, int numGamesToPlay) {…}
```

I want to make this threadable using the .NET 4.6 TPL in C#. I want to launch up to 8 of these functions at once, wait until they all finish, capture the results and move on.

I can’t seem to get the types right and it’s not working as expected.

Here’s what I’ve got so far:

```
Task<int[]> PlayGames(int[][] boardToSearch, int numGamesToPlay) {…code that takes a long time…}

private int FindBestMove(int[][] boardToSearch, int numGamesToPlay)
{
    …
    var taskList = new List<Task>();

    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return PlayGames(boardToSearch, numGamesToPlay); }));
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return PlayGames(boardToSearch, numGamesToPlay); }));   

    // Tests
     Task a = taskList.First();

     var a1 = a.Result; // NOT ALLOWED!? Viewable in debugger, cannot access it.

     var b = Task.FromResult(a); 

     var b1 = b.Result; // Works but cannot access child member Result. Debugger sees it, I can’t!?     

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    …
}
```

Here are my questions

1. How do I remove the lambda expression `() => { return PlayGames(boardToSearch, numGamesToPlay); }`? I want to use `Func()` somehow but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to say “`Task.Factory.StartNew<int[]>(Func(PlayGames(boardToSearch, numGamesToPlay)))`”.
2. Why do I need to use `StartNew()`? When I do `taskList.Add(PlayGames(int[][] boardToSearch, int numGamesToPlay))`, it does it synchronously!? What is the correct syntax to add a task to a list in this manner? Do I need to declare a Func of some sorts that I pass to something like `new Task(Func(PlayGames))`?
3. When you look at variable a after executing the line Task a = taskList.First(), it clearly shows a member called Result in the debug pane. And if I expand that result it contains the right data! But if I click on add watch to the Result member, I get an error! And if I do a.Result, the compiler gives me the same error!?? So the debugger says it’s there but I cannot view it on its own!?? I can browse it from the a object but not directly. I included a screenshot of this so others could see.
4. What is the cleanest way to do this with .NET 4.6 while staying away from lambda expressions. I want to see all the types and the declarations.

Attached is a screenshot of my debugger so you can see what I mean with `.Result`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the top:

1] Func it's just a delegate that's the part of .net framework libraries.
So, when you pass `() => { return PlayGames(boardToSearch, numGamesToPlay); }` it means you just create an anonymous method which has a type of `Func<int[]>`. If you assign this lambda expression to some variable then you can check this type.
If you don't want to use lambda you can write a common method and put it inside the task: `Task.Factory.StartNew(YourMethodWhichReturnsIntArray)`.

2] When you call `StartNew()` method it just creates a new `Task` and starts execute this. That's it.
`taskList.Add(PlayGames(int[][] boardToSearch, int numGamesToPlay))` - this just put the `Task` into the `taskList`. If inside your `PlayGames` method this `Task` wasn't started then you will need to do it sometime after. Synchronous or not - adding `Task` to list is synchronous operation, but executing still will be asynchronous. Any syntax might be correct or not - it depends on complexity and realization. Instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, you can you a just `Task.Run()` method. It does the same, but in a bit shorten manner. And it's not necessary to declare a func before passing to the `Task`.

3] I believe is that's because the `debugger` has an ability to wait for the results from a parallel thread/task, but `watcher` doesn't. That's why you get an error.
So, I would say do not try to add watcher for the parallel threads results (just to skip the possible errors).

4] What is the cleanest way to do this with .NET 4.6 while staying away from lambda expressions. I want to see all the types and the declarations.

As I said above, it's not necessary to declare the lambda. You can create a method with the correspond definition. But here you will face some difficulties with passing the parameters to this method (but they still could be solved). So, lambda - is the easiest way to pass function to the `Task`, because it can easily capture you parameters from the scope where these lambda's have been created.

`What is the cleanest way` - again, it depends. Each of us has his own cleanest way to run new tasks. So, I think that (see below):

```
// your function
int[] PlayGames(int[][] boardToSearch, int numGamesToPlay) {…}

private int YouMethodToRun8Tasks(int[][] boardToSearch, int numGamesToPlay)
{
    ...
    var taskList = new List<Task<int[]>>();

    // create and run 8 tasks
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        // it will capture the parameters and use them in all 8 tasks
        taskList.Add(Task.Run<int[]>(() => PlayGames(boardToSearch, numGamesToPlay));
    }
    // do something else
    ...   

    // wait for all tasks
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    // do something else
}
```

might be named as cleanest way in some cases.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I just made my code like this but how do I access the result? It will not let me do this

'foreach (var taskGameResults in taskList)
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    moveAverageScores[i] += taskGameResults.Result;'

I get 'Error CS1061 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

This is the same error I was describing above. It's driving me nuts as this appears simple! Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: To get access to result you need to use the `Task<TResult>` instead of `Task`.  I edited the answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. If you have time, can you simply show me how to declare everything so that I do not need to pass a lambda expression to Task.Run? It's ok if it adds another type. I just want to see how it's done.

Also, I forgot to add the <int[]> to Task.Run and it still worked!? Shouldn't I get an error? It works both ways. To me they seem to be two different types no?

Comment: It's not necessary in your case to add `<int[]>` to `Task.Run` because `TResult` will be determined from the result of your lambda. You shouldn't get an error. 

if you don't want to pass a lambda to `Task.Run` you can declare you lambda as a variable and pass this variable to `Task.Run`. That's the only way because you need to capture some parameters from the parent scope.